# Can you patent an DialogFlow Bot?

Tags: patentability, software, utility-model

> Dialogflow is a Google-owned developer of human–computer interaction
>   technologies based on natural language conversations. The company is
>   best known for creating the Assistant, a virtual buddy for Android,
>   iOS, and Windows Phone smartphones that performs tasks and answers
>   users' question in a natural language.

- I have an idea and created a Dialogflow Assistant/Bot used for
  user-software interaction.
- The Bot is not for general public usage.
- The Bot can be used by Software Managers/Engineers/Architects from different projects in the Information technology industry.
- For each project, a new/specific Bot has to be created using my idea.
- This Bot is currently in testing/alpha stage.

My knowledge of patents is very limited. Any help is appreciated,

- First of all, can I patent something like this?
- If yes, can I patent the Bot/Assistant which I create?
- Or, can I patent the Idea(Business Logic) used in the Bot/Assistant which does a specific job when used??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I attempt to answer let me state that I am not a lawyer, but I do have several algorithm based patents. The bottom line is that it is complicated and you can't get a definitive answer from a Q&A site such as this because you can't tell us what you are actually trying to do. That said, algorithm based patents do exist but they can be hard to acquire.

Algorithms by themselves are probably not patentable because they would be considered "abstract". The application of an algorithm to solving a specific problem might be patentable, but it still needs to meet the normal requirements of a patent which is novelty, non-obviousness and utility.

The bottom line is you really need to consult with a patent attorney or agent to determine the patentability of your idea. Indeed, you should find one who is experienced with software patents in particular. Even though it is theoretically possible to draft and file a patent application without an attorney or agent, it is extremely hard to do so successfully especially with software related patents.